# How do I decode data in mysql field that is in this format?

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I have fields in my database that I need to decode or view in a more simple format.  I'm not sure what method was used to create this format though I've seen it before.  This is data from a web form in a MySQL table. What do I use in PHP or MySQL to decode this when I retrieve it from the database?

`a:10:{s:10:&quot;First Name&quot;;s:10:&quot;cvsgjsrhlw&quot;;s:9:&quot;Last Name&quot;;s:10:&quot;cvsgjsrhlw&quot;;s:7:&quot;Address&quot;;s:26:&quot;http://www.tlneepxlni.com/&quot;;s:4:&quot;City&quot;;s:7:&quot;Atlanta&quot;;s:5:&quot;State&quot;;s:2:&quot;AL&quot;;s:8:&quot;Zip Code&quot;;s:0:&quot;&quot;;s:9:&quot;Best time&quot;;s:7:&quot;Mid-day&quot;;s:6:&quot;Other2&quot;;s:8:&quot;cqoeqipd&quot;;s:14:&quot;Procedure face&quot;;s:18:&quot;Laser Hair Removal&quot;;s:4:&quot;when&quot;;s:22:&quot;In the  next 4 months.&quot;;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a built in php serialization

You need to use [`unserialize`](https://www.php.net/unserialize)

Answer (score 1):

This is [serialize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)'d code. It is a way to multiple data types as plain text. You can convert it back to a php object with [`unserialize($data)`](https://www.php.net/unserialize)

If you are writing new code, I would recommend using [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/json_encode) instead

Answer (score 1):

This is a serialized array. Use:

```
 $data_array = unserialize($data_from_db);
```

Comment: where $data_from_db = "a:10:{s:10:&quot;First Name&quot;;s:10:&quot;cvsgjsrhlw&quot;;s:9:&quot;Last Name&quot;;s:10:&quot;cvsgjsrhlw&quot;;s:7:&quot;Address&quot;;s:26:&quot;http://www.tlneepxlni.com/&quot;;s:4:&quot;City&quot;;s:7:&quot;Atlanta&quot;;s:5:&quot;State&qtime&quot;;s:7:&quot;Mid-day&quot;;s:6:&quot;Other2&quot;;s:8:&quot;cqoeqipd&quot;;s:14:&quot;Procedure face&quot;;s:18:&quot;Laser Hair Removal&quot;;s:4:&quot;when&quot;;s:22:&quot;In the  next 4 months.&quot;;}"; ?  

echo $data_array or print_r($data_array);

Comment: I now have it working.  thanks,  I also had to ...

$data_array = unserialize(str_replace('&quot;','"',$data_from_db));

print_r($data_array);